# EF codefirst charset

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use `entity framework code first` approach. On database creation seed method populates data into table. Unfortunately i can't figure out how to set `charset` to populate ***NOT English*** words correctly into database.

Seed text:
[image]

Database data:
[image]

I tried to add Charset=utf 8 into connection string but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Open your's Configuration.cs file in Solution Explorer, copy Seed method and paste code in Windows Notepad for example (temporarily).

Next close Configuration.cs in Visual Studio if you have it opened, then right-click on that file in Solution Explorer and select "Open With..." -> "CSharp Editor with Encoding" and from a list choose "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" option (try different option when this one will show you some 'chinese' characters).

Replace Seed method with that from Notepad. Save, delete existing data from database and Update-Databse. Your country characters shoud now display correctly.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("VARCHAR"));
```